# How to validate one entry by one user for current date?

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing and employee attendance portal for which i want to restrict user's to make one entry for a particular date.
So, that one can't have duplicated value of attendance for  current date.

```
    require('../config1.php');
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
    $Username=$_SESSION['sess_user'];
    $Ptype= mysqli_escape_string($con, $_POST['ptype']);
    $Time = time();
    $TimeIN = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$Time);
    $Date = CURDATE('');
    $Day = date('N');



    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO presence(pid,username,ptype,timein,date,pday) 
    VALUES (NULL,'$Username','$Ptype','$TimeIN','$Date','$Day')") 
    or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

So, with my current code one user is able to make multiple entry for same day.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of dealing with this problem.

**IN PHP**:
First thing, you could check before inserting that there is no row in the table `presence` with the same username & date and then decide whether to insert your datas or not.

```
require('../config1.php');
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
    $Username=$_SESSION['sess_user'];
    $Ptype= mysqli_escape_string($con, $_POST['ptype']);
    $Time = time();
    $TimeIN = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$Time);
    $Date = CURDATE('');
    $Day = date('N');

    $req_pre = mysqli_prepare($bdd, 'select pid from presence where username=? and date=?');
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($req_pre, $Username, $Date);
    //If the row is there, then your user has already registered, else he hasn't.

    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO presence(pid,username,ptype,timein,date,pday) VALUES (NULL,'$Username','$Ptype','$TimeIN','$Date','$Day')") or die(mysqli_error($con));
}
```

**IN BOTH PHP AND SQL**:
I don't know your sgbd so you'll have to determine the exact syntax of the solution.
I don't know how you've set your unique index, but you can have multiple column define your unique index and thus it'll ensure that there is only one row at the time in the table in sql.
For example in mysql it would be

```
ALTER TABLE `presence` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`username`, `date`);
```

Is that all ? Not really, if you add a user into your table presence with the same $username and $date then your php will return an error. Mysqli doesn't naturally send throw error so you'll have to handle them by hand (of build a system to throw them). Here is a turnaround

```
  require('../config1.php');
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
    $Username=$_SESSION['sess_user'];
    $Ptype= mysqli_escape_string($con, $_POST['ptype']);
    $Time = time();
    $TimeIN = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$Time);
    $Date = CURDATE('');
    $Day = date('N');

    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO presence(pid,username,ptype,timein,date,pday) 
    VALUES (NULL,'$Username','$Ptype','$TimeIN','$Date','$Day')");
    if (mysqli_errno == 1062) {
        //There it is a duplicate entry
        print 'no way!';
    }
```

Note that it will only catch the "DUPLICATE" error, and not other errors.

I hope this will help you

Comment: Kudos's it worked for me >>Well i preferred **PHP AND MYSQL**
When user tries to make entry again it gives **Duplicate entry 'mishravibhor' for key 'username**
How can this error text can be made more user friendly

Comment: you can do wathever you want in the catch part to display properly the error :).

Comment: I appreciate your prompt response but it's giving the error as earlier
Could you please help out with the exact syntax
**if user tries to make additional entry for the same day**

Comment: **Fatal error** : Call to undefined method mysqli::errorno()

Comment: Well can you suggest to have dynamic interfaced page.
If the employee select absent(drop-down list) then, a text field comes where he can enter the reason for being absent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INSERT IGNORE INTO` query to achieve your goal. It will insert the row if it does not exists and simply ignores the query if the row already exists. So if the person already marked the attendance then next attempt will be simply ignored.
You can refer this link for more details: http://bogdan.org.ua/2007/10/18/mysql-insert-if-not-exists-syntax.html

Example:

```
"INSERT IGNORE INTO 'presence' 
SET 'pid'=NULL,
'username' =$Username,
'ptype' = $Ptype,
'timein' = $TimeIN,
'date' = $Date,
'pday' = $Day;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could let the `INSERT` statement make the test. Note that you can skip the *pid* column, as you pass *null* anyway:

```sql
INSERT INTO presence(username, ptype, timein, `date`, pday) 
SELECT '$Username', '$Ptype', '$TimeIN', '$Date', '$Day'
FROM   dual
WHERE  ('$Username', '$Date') NOT IN
       (SELECT  username, `date`
        FROM    presence)
```

Note that `FROM dual` is just there because the syntax requires the `FROM` clause. Also, as *date* is a reserved word, you better put backticks around that.

If you would allow multiple records when *ptype* is different, then add that column to the `WHERE` clause and sub-query as well.

Then in your PHP code you can check whether a row was inserted or not:

```
if (mysqli_affected_rows($con) == 0) {
    // duplicate detected. No insert done.
    echo "You cannot enter another presence for the same day";
}
```

### Alternative

If it is a general rule (also in potentially other code), that such duplicates can **never** be allowed to exist in your table, then you should define this on the database level, like so:

```sql
ALTER TABLE presence
    ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_username_date (username, `date`);
```

Before you can do the above, you have to make sure there are no such duplicates in your table already, otherwise the statement will complain about that.

Then in your code check for any errors and report them:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, 
    "INSERT INTO presence(username, ptype, timein, `date`, pday) 
     VALUES ('$Username', '$Ptype', '$TimeIN', '$Date', '$Day')");
if (!$result) { 
    // INSERT did not happen. 
    if (mysqli_errno($con) == 1062) { // Duplicate entry 
        // Treat duplicate
        echo "You cannot enter another presence for the same day";
    } else {
        // another error occurred: report it and exit.
        echo mysqli_errno($con) . " - " . mysqli_error($con)
        exit();
    }
}
```

Whether you want to *exit* also after you display the "duplicate" message, depends on whether you want to still execute the rest of the code.

Comment: although it work first for the first time but doesn't takes another entry although on different date.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what doesn't work? If you created the index correctly, it should be OK. Please give a concrete example of what fails, so I can look into it. Also, tell me how it fails: error message, or ...